# Disambiguate the [format] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The tag [format](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format) is used for several unrelated meanings.

It is used for:

- “format a drive” = make a filesystem → [mkfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mkfs) (should we have a more discoverable synonym for people who are new to unix?)
- “format a drive” = partition a disk → [partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partition)
- file formats → [file-format](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-format)
- text markup → [text-formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-formatting)
- `printf` formats → [printf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/printf) [retagged 3]
- `date` formats → [date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) [retagged 3]
- ?

There are <strike>50 43 36 23 4</strike> 0 questions with this tag. We're done.

Comment: I added a tag wiki for [text-formatting](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/text-formatting/info).

Answer (score 11):

I think the use of [format](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format) to mean creating a file system is going to be hard to eradicate. As you point out, most people won't know what `mkfs` is while *format* is a household term. This is always going to be a hard tag to deal with since it can be used to mean so many different things.

The best solution I can see would be to blacklist the tag. Then, when someone tries to use it, we give them a message like:

[image: blacklisted tag warning, showing available alternative tags]

The above is just a  mockup, we can tweak both the text and the alternative tags shown. If we decide this is the way to go, I will ask an SE employee to implement it (as far as I know, mods don't have access to the blacklisting tools).

---

UPDATE:

This is now live, attempting to use [format](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format) brings up this message:

[image: real blacklisted tag warning, showing available alternative tags]

Answer (score 4):

For your first bullet, I suggest replacing [mkfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mkfs) with [filesystem-creation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filesystem-creation) or [fs-creation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fs-creation) if the former is too long. This way, new users with a question about creating a filesystem and who don't know `mkfs` will have more chance to select the relevant tag.

Comment: Good point. It might be worth it to create a synonym but let's see how  the blacklisting goes first.